# Is it possible to begin then end a VkCommandBuffer multiple times before submitting it in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I want to know if it is possible to begin recording commands into a command buffer, then end the command buffer before starting it again (with `vkBeginCommandBuffer`) while still maintaining all the commands recorded in the first begin-end session. Is this possible in vulkan?

For example, can you:

```
vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

vkCmdFoo(commandBuffer, ...);

vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

// then later on:

vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

vkCmdBar(commandBuffer, ...)

vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

// finally, submit the command buffer
vkQueueSubmit(...)
```

And if you can do this, is it guaranteed that vkCmdFoo and vkCmdBar would both be recorded in the command buffer?

Thanks!

Comment: Um, why would you *want* to do that? I mean, even if it worked, that doesn't sound like a good idea from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You can only begin recording a command buffer once, unless you reset and lose the current content. If you want multiple begin/end cycles you would need to use multiple command buffers. Alternatively use one, and defer the `vkEndCommandBuffer()` until you know you are really done.

See the lifecycle in the spec here:

- https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#commandbuffers-lifecycle